# CSS3: Nested flexbox form messes up spacing

Tags: html, forms, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a flexbox form with label and input on the same line. Using flex-basis and and other flex properties gives the expected and desired result.

However, if one has to nest that flexbox inside another element with a set width, the whole thing falls apart.

E.g. see the attached fiddle and run it with and without the `div {width:30%}`

How can I get around this?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/fjqjrs9j/)

Comment: Give that div a background and you can see how the contents are overflowing. Start with a `min-width`: https://jsfiddle.net/zcj2vaLh/

Comment: @misterManSam if you mess with the `min-width` however it just picks that over `width:30%`. I dont want to manually set the width....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make `flexbox` behave as a grid/table, and as it is not made for that you need to help it a little by setting some constraint, like `min-width`, though as you stated you don't want that, use a proper display type.

Since CSS Grid still has no reasonable browser support, here is the second best, CSS Table

```css
div.lesswide {
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
form  {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
form div {
  display: table-row;
}
form label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
form input {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>A</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>LONG</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>SOMEWHAT LONGER</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>INTHEMIDDLE</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="lesswide">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>A</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>LONG</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>SOMEWHAT LONGER</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>INTHEMIDDLE</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

An updated version based on comments

```css
form {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
form > div {
  display: table-row;
}
form label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
form input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form div div:first-child {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
form div div:last-child {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70%;
}

form div .side-by-side input[type=button] {
  width: 30%;
}
form div .side-by-side input[type=submit] {
  width: 70%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  form div div:first-child,
  form div div:last-child,
  form label {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>A</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>LONG</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>SOMEWHAT LONGER</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>INTHEMIDDLE</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="Button">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>A</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>LONG</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>SOMEWHAT LONGER</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>INTHEMIDDLE</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div class="side-by-side">
        <input type="button" value="Button"><input type="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: indeed. One last follow-up. How come if I specify `input[type=text]` and then try to add two buttons in the same line (1 30% the other 70%) they just stay on the left? https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/hmv829ce/6/

Comment: @SumNeuron Post that code piece in a fiddle and I'll have a look .... I also suggest we delete all the above comments as they kind of don't add anything for future user, agree?

Comment: agreed. Th fiddle is in the previous comment :)

Comment: @SumNeuron Well, form elements really don't like to be other than just that, so wrapping them is actually the proper way: https://jsfiddle.net/hmv829ce/8/

Comment: @SumNeuron Updated my answer with a 2:nd sample

Answer (score 0):

You can add `width:100%;`  to form div

https://jsfiddle.net/fjqjrs9j/1/

Comment: that didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this flexible `flexbox Form`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,800");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "Open Sans", helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h1,
h5 {
  text-align: center;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.ruler {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 30px -320px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 6px;
  line-height: -20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.ruler span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 80px;
  top: -22px;
  left: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #efefef;
}

textarea,
input {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #454545;
}

textarea:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

textarea {
  height: 300px;
}

.flexy-parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flexy-item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 300px;
  flex: 1 0 300px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Flex Form</h1>
  <h5>SIZE WINDOW</h5>
  <div class="ruler"><span>640px</span></div>
  <section class="flexy-parent">
    <input class="flexy-item" type="text" placeholder="Responsive input fields...">
    <input class="flexy-item" type="text" placeholder="will break at 640px...">
  </section>
  <section class="flexy-parent">
    <input class="flexy-item" type="text" placeholder="flex-grow: 1">
    <input class="flexy-item" type="text" placeholder="flex-basis: 300px">
  </section>
  <section class="flexy-parent">
    <textarea class="flexy-item" placeholder="And thanks to flexbox, everything stays nice and tidy."></textarea>
  </section>
</main>
```